# [android][appium] how to click on element with no resource-id?

Tags: android, appium

I can't figure out how to click on the sign-in element (from UI Automator):
[image]

Keep in mind there are multiple TextView-s with 0-index in the UI. Can I use its text ("Sign in") or its unique ListView/TextView path somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

First, try this:

```
driver.findElementByName("SignIn").click();
```

Second, try this:

```
public void tap(int index){
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElementByClass("PUT YOUR class name");
li.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that findElementByName() searches for the text, worked. I chose your answer because of the example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what version of Android you are running on, but what you can do is

1) You can try to add content description to XML element search for it.

2) You can search by text as you said, such as searching for name ("Sign in").

3) You can access using XPath.

I would recommend setting up **[Appium Ruby Console](https://github.com/GokhanArik/ruby_console)**, so you can test commands in real time and see what works best for you.

Comment: As a tester, unfortunately, I can't change change source code. +1 for the ruby console suggestion, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: It works in the opposite way with the Appium UI app. In the app, you get the code by element. In the console, you reach to the element writing code. I used and it is pretty cool. Let me know if you run into any issues configuring it.

Answer (score 2):

In native android automation I do something like,

```
onData(anything())
.inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
        .atPosition(0).atPosition(1)
        .perform(click()); //this click item in droplist within droplist
```

or

```
onView(findChildof(withId(R.id.parent_id), 3)).check(matches((isDisplayed()))).perform(click()); //this clicks third child
```

Comment: This would work, unfortunately I am confined to python

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and @index='0']")).click();
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Sign In")).click();
```

Ideally Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name and text for clicking.
There is no need of building custom xpath for this.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("class"));
For(WebElement element:elements)
{
    if(element.geText().equals("textProperty"))
    {
        element.click();
    }
}
```